# Detecting "Bad Request" or 404 in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Is there a way to detect these website errors in iframes? I am working on a app that has a third party website that has to be embedded into an iframe (trust me I'm not happy about it.) and we have to be able to hide the iframe if these errors occur.

What is the most graceful way to handle this? I have tried a .error, but have had no success. Help would be appreciated so I can keep my brain intact and not have it explode everywhere.

Comment: If it is a 3rd party iframe, there really is not much you can do about it.

Comment: it's a requirement coming from up top, I have to figure out at least something.

Comment: Well same origin policy trumps what you can do in the clientside

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not.

If iframe is coming from diferent source and doesn't allow access( [X-Frame-Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39625049/detecting-bad-request-or-404-in-iframe) ), you can't do anything about it.

read about it here [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

There are few things, however, you can do:

If those are singular clicks (people don't navigate further) you can just make request and check content and then actually open iframe.

You can add in app browser like Linkedin for example. Take a look at [cordova in app](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) that is really specific solution, different for each platform, but it removes need of iframe.